# Get text from table in .docx file using python

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to get full text of document as python string. So, I use docx library:

```
doc = docx.Document(user_file)
fullText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
   fullText.append(para.text)
text = '\n'.join(fullText)
```

It works, but ignore text in tables. How should I get data from tables? Maybe there is any way to clear tags or somehow prepare document? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`doc.tables`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.tables) returns a list of Table instances corresponding to the tables in the document, in document order. Note that only tables appearing at the top level of the document appear in this list; a table nested inside a table cell does not appear. A table within revision marks such as <w:ins> or <w:del> will also not appear in the list.